# Every bounded Borel set can be _perfectly_ approximated by a countable union of disjoint open intervals?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

This feels wrong to me, but I seem to be able to *perfectly approximate* every bounded Borel set using a countable union of disjoint open intervals. By *perfectly*, I mean that the Lebesgue measure of the *symmetric difference* between the Borel set and my approximation is zero.

Assume a Borel set $B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is bounded, and so $B \subseteq (a_0, b_0)$ for some $a_0, b_0 \in \mathbb{R}$. For each $x \in B$, we consider the *maximal* interval $(a_x, b_x) \ni x$ such that $\lambda((a_x, b_x) \triangle B) = 0$, where $\lambda$ is the Lebesgue measure and $X \triangle Y := (X\backslash Y) \cup (Y \backslash X)$ denotes the symmetric difference. More precisely, \begin{align*} a_x &:= \inf \{ a \in \mathbb{R}: a \leq x, \lambda((a, x) \triangle B) = 0 \}, \\ b_x &:= \sup \{ b \in \mathbb{R}: b \geq x, \lambda((x, b) \triangle B) = 0 \}.\end{align*} We end up with disjoint intervals, because if $x \in I$ and $x \in J$ for some intervals $I$ and $J$, then we must have $I \cup J \in (a_x, b_x)$ by maximality of the interval $(a_x, b_x)$. Moreover, every open interval contains a rational number, and *iF yOu BeLiEvE iN tHe AxIoM oF cHoIcE*, we can choose a rational representative of every interval, and so this is a countable union.

Denote this countable union by $S := \cup_{n \in \mathbb{N}}I_n$. Then $\lambda(S \triangle B) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \lambda (I_n \triangle B) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} 0 = 0$ since the $I_n \triangle B$ are disjoint and a countable sum of zeros is zero.

The above feels wrong, but I can't see what's wrong with my reasoning. Where did I make a mistake?

**EDIT**

@user14111 pointed out a typo above that's been fixed now.

**ANOTHER EDIT**

Thanks to @user14111 in his first comment below, I think I see my mistake now. Essentially, I implicitly sort of assumed that "only dense bits of a set can generate positive measure", if that makes sense. In my argument above, for each $x \in B$, we could have the case $a_x = x = b_x$, but I didn't mention it because then trivially we have $(a_x, b_x) = \emptyset$ and we could just ignore it, but **we can't just ignore it**, because for example the fat Cantor set is nowhere dense (meaning all of the $(a_x, b_x)$ would be $\emptyset$) but it nevertheless has positive measure.

Comment: How does this work if $B$ is a compact nowhere dense set of positive measure, e.g., a fat Cantor set? By the way, what happens if $a_x=x=b_x$?

Comment: Where did you use the assumption that $B$ is a Borel set?

Comment: In the second paragraph you wrote "For each $x\in B$, we consider the maximal interval $(a_x,b_x)$ such that .. .[a condition that does not mention $x$]" Typo?

Comment: @user14111 Thank you for looking into this. Yes I should have mentioned $x$ when talking about $(a_x, b_x)$. Regarding $B$ being a Borel set, I think the fact that it's measurable with the Lebesgue measure implicitly assumes that $B$ is a Borel set, no? Also, if $a_x = x = b_x$ then we have an empty interval, which we just ignore, no? Finally, I wasn't aware of the fat Cantor set or indeed any set that is nowhere dense but has positive measure; I'll look into it. I think that may break my argument above, but still, where exactly is the flaw in my argument?

Comment: @user14111 I think I see my mistake now. Thank you. The fat Cantor set is indeed a counter example.

Comment: @user14111 the reason I had this question was because of the following question, which I really really want an answer to, and have spent many many days to solve, only in vain. Can you help?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/216579/approximating-borel-sets-by-finite-unions-of-intervals